# How can I find the temporary directory on Windows using Rust? (Like /tmp on Unix-like)

Tags: windows, rust, temporary

What would be the easiest way to find the temporary file directory on Windows (The equivalent of `/tmp` on Unix-like OSes)? Is it saved on an environment variable, or is it always a specific one? I want to find it for a Rust crate, so Rust-only answers. If possible I'd like to avoid anything but the `std` crate.

Comment: [`std::env::temp_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.temp_dir.html)

Comment: Can you make this an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Possible with std only of course, but do consider using [`tempfile`](https://docs.rs/tempfile/latest/tempfile/) instead of re-implementing its functionality.

Comment: Not possible to use `tempfile` for a variety of reasons. Otherwise I'd use it.

Comment: @AggelosT: Even if you can't use `tempfile`, you would likely want to use `tempdir` (also documented in Caesar's link) to isolate the files from temp files used by other programs (and make cleanup easier). If neither one of them applies, there's a decent chance you have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) and are misusing the system temporary directory (if you think it's persistent in any way, and rely on that, in any way, things will break eventually).

Comment: I can just create my own directory and remove it, no need for another dependency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::env::temp_dir()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.temp_dir.html) returns a path to the system temporary directory. According to the docs when this answer was posted,

> On Windows, the behavior is equivalent to that of [`GetTempPath2`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppath2a) / [`GetTempPath`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppatha), which this function uses internally.